# puppeteer evaluate functions not accepting JSHandles or ElementHandles as variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I can pass native objects (strings, lists, numbers, etc) just fine, but whenever I try to pass in a JSHandle or ElementHandle, I get this error msg: "**TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Are you passing a nested JSHandle? at JSON.stringify ()**"

This is my code:

```
    async getColumnsNames(id='dashboardGrid') {
    await this.loadObjects();
    const grid = this.table
    const detectedColumns = await this.page.evaluate(({grid}) => {
        //const grid = document.getElementById(id)
        const header = grid.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-viewport')[0]
        const labelRow = header.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-row')[0]
        const cells = labelRow.getElementsByClassName('ag-header-cell-text')
        var children = []
        for(x = 0; x < cells.length; x++) {
             cells[x].innerText.length > 0 ? children.push(cells[x].innerText) : null
        }
        return children
    }, {grid});
    console.log(detectedColumns)
}
```

So if I pass 'id' to obtain inside the 'grid' element, no problem (it's a CSS selector), but if I try to pass a handle (grid) directly, I get that error msg.

Said handle is exactly this:

```
this.table = await this.page.$(this.tableID);
```

Which totally works elsewhere for detecting the corresponding DOM element (this.tableID is '[id="dashboardGrid"]'), so I know the handle is NOT the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you build your first argument like this `{grid}`, the resulting object is not an instance of `JSHandle`, so the evaluate won't treat that correctly.

This should work

```js
const detectedColumns = await this.page.evaluate(grid => {
//Some code
}, grid);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm getting awfully confused with all the different ways to pass parameters in puppeteer (migrating from casperjs and phantomjs), so this sure helps (I also just discovered I can invoke the eval methods directly on my JSHandle object,which will definitely help (need to build an agGrid library to manipulate agGrid objects to test with jestJS)